# Can't connect with BOLT to a docker Neo4j

Tags: python, docker, neo4j

I run a docker instance of Neo4j :

```
docker run -d \
--publish=7474:7474 \
--publish=7687:7687 \
--volume=/home/jeff/tmp/neo4j:/data neo4j
```

The IP given with a "docker inspect" is : 172.17.0.2. I can connect to Neo4j into the browser, and change the password.

Then, start a bash instance in Docker :

```
docker run -it ubuntu:16.04 bash
apt-get update
apt-get install python3
apt-get install python3-pip
pip3 install neo4j-driver
apt-get install nano
nano test.py
```

The python script "test.py" is :

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase, basic_auth

session = GraphDatabase.driver(
    'bolt://172.17.0.2',
    auth=basic_auth('neo4j', '******')
    ).session()

session.run('MATCH (n) RETURN n')
```

Then :

```
chmod +x test.py
./test.py
```

I get this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./test.py", line 11, in <module>
session.run('MATCH (n) RETURN n')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/neo4j/v1/bolt.py", line 145, in run
self.connection.send()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/neo4j/bolt/connection.py", line 344, in send
raise ServiceUnavailable("Failed to write to closed connection %r" % (self.server.address,))
neo4j.bolt.connection.ServiceUnavailable: Failed to write to closed connection Address(host='172.17.0.2', port=7687)
```

Outside of the container, i mean on the host machine, the test.py script works fine. Any idea ?

-- EDIT --

Inside the container, 'ip a' gives :

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
18: eth0@if19: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:04 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.17.0.4/16 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:acff:fe11:4/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Can you give the result of `ifconfig -a` command from inside your docker image ?

Comment: Added in "EDIT" part. I can alos say that a ping to the Neo4j serveur works : (ping 172.17.0.2)

Answer (score 2):

The IP inside the container "172.17.0.4", does not match the one you specify in the script, "172.17.0.2". I suspect Python attempted to bind to the latter, failed, and returned a closed socket. Then when Neo4j went to send, it errored on a closed socket. Search for "failed to write" on [this page](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/_modules/neo4j/bolt/connection.html).

Try setting the script to use one of these as the address:

- "172.17.0.4" - bind to the interface based on results of 'ip a'
- "0.0.0.0" - bind to all available interfaces.

Comment: this is due to different tests. IP were the same.